# UITableView background color does not change

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In a model UIViewController I have the following implementation of loadView (everything is created programmatically):

```
- (void)loadView {

    // Add Basic View
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540, 620)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view = myView;
    [myView release];

    // Add NavigationBar

    // Add a BG image

    // Add Table
    UITableView *tbView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 80, 480, 250) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    tbView.dataSource = self;
    tbView.delegate = self;
    tbView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    tbView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [tbView reloadData];

    [self.view addSubview:tbView];
    [tbView release];

    // some more code
}
```

As you can see I set backgroundColor to clearColor, yet when I compile and run the code I always see a gray background behind the table:
[image]

I don't understand what I am doing wrong (sounds stupid, I know), I used to have the very same code and it worked perfectly fine. I am compiling with iOS SDK 4.2.1

Comment: You shouldn't be doing all this setup in `loadView`, it should be in `viewDidLoad`. In `loadView` you should *just* create the view, not set colors, etc. Its ok to set the frame to `CGRectZero` in `loadView`. You can change it later in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You also need to set your UITableView's backgroundView property to nil on recent (since 3.2) versions of iOS.

As such, adding...

```
tbView.backgroundView = nil;
```

...should sort your problems.

That said, if you want to maintain compatibilty with pre-3.2 devices, you should check for the existence of this via the `instancesRespondToSelector` method before calling it.

Comment: that worked, thanks! I don't quite understand why they added this view though, what would be the difference to just adding the UITableView as a subview of any custom view?

Comment: @Robin I suppose it's a cleaner path if the UITableView is effectively your top level view, but that's pretty much it.

Comment: It's weird that I never had to do this until just recently.  +1

Answer (score 14):

Make sure you have the following 3 options set:

```
tbView.opaque = NO;
tbView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tbView.backgroundView  = nil;
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to put the code in the `viewWillAppear`. It did not work if I put it in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: @Guruniverse That response is what fixed my problem after over an hour of searching. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

try

```
tbView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to change from storyboard.
It works fine in

```
tbView.backgroundColor = .white
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.x
I came across this problem recently.
The old solution helped (and in my case it was - only in this sequence):

```
    tableView.backgroundView = nil
    tableView.isOpaque = false
    tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```