# UITableView background View nil doesn't work in iOS 5

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I need to make my grouped `UITableView` `backgroundColor` transparent.

So i write following code. That is work in iOS 6. But in iOS 5, it doesn't work.

```
self.tbView.backgroundView = nil;
```

How to do that in iOS 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it answer.
We need to add two lines of codes for both iOS 6 and iOS 5.

Here is codes.

```
self.tblPreferences.backgroundView = nil;
self.myTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

That is working both iOS 5 and 6.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting `[self.tbView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`?

If not, you need to add that or you won't get a transparent backgorund color.

Answer (score 1):

You Need to put background Nil code into `ViewDidLoad` this is working fine in my Code. Hope this Helps you.

```
    [tbl_My_Table setBackgroundView:nil];
    [tbl_My_Table setBackgroundView:[[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease]];
```

Comment: yes i set background to nil in ViewDidLoad. But doesn't work in iOS 5.

Comment: add One more line tbl_My_Table.opaque = NO; before [tbl_My_Table setBackgroundView:nil]; also check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785659/uitableview-background-color-does-not-change clear your Project Build and remove project from simulator or device. run again and check it

Comment: i think you did Mistake some other place check xib table IBOutlate

Comment: i got it bro.I need to set both lines of following codes. Thanks you for your help bro. self.tblPreferences.backgroundView = nil;
self.myTable.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];