# UITableView background color won't change

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, background

I know this question has been asked before and i've been searching for hours now but I just can't find the answer. I want to change the color of the table that shows when u drag down the table on the absolute top as here:

[Picture](http://tinypic.com/r/v8065z/8)

The part between the searchbox and the segmented control.
I'm not sure which element it is where I have to change the color. I tried everything I could find over the interface builder (table, searchbar, cell) and it seems like nothing can help.
I read this post about changing the UITableView's background color but that also didn't do the job for me: [Post about background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4785659/uitableview-background-color-does-not-change)

I know that when I usually change the color of the underlying view of the table that this background color changes, but not in this table so i thought something is might overlapping.

**UPDATE**
I figured that this only happens when I add a search bar with search display controller, but I still dont know where to change the background color there.

So maybe someone could tell me which element it is that I'm trying to change.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UITableView clear background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753411/uitableview-clear-background)

Answer (score 0):

- Set the background color of the UITableView in ViewDidLoad Method not in XIB.

> - (void)viewDidLoad {
>
>   [super viewDidLoad];
>
>   self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
>
> }

- And CellForROwAtIndexPathMethod,mention the Background color of cell and ContentView of Cell to Clear Color.

  > -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  >   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
  >   .....
  >
  > ```
  > cell.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
  > cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  > ....
  > ```
  >
  > }

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Hey thanks for replying but I tried all of this and I doesnt seem to work. I dont think this is the source of my problem if you have a look at the update of my initial post